# Play framework testing controller method

Tags: unit-testing, playframework

I have a controller method that fetches data to render(fetched data) a HTML view of the same. I wanted to write a test to ensure the jpa model is queried correctly. However I am not finding a way to intercept what is being passed into render().

Can someone please let me know if there is a way to get what is passed into render from a test case. If not should I move this code/line into a different class that I can test easily.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactly what you want but you could just write some selenium tests that will confirm whether the controller is rendering the correct data in the template.  (see: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide10#selenium)

Also writing a Functional Test may help (see: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide10#controller)

Answer (score 0):

Could you see if the [Play Response](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.4/play/mvc/Http.Response.html) object i.e. the out contains your expected value?